# Why my js onclick event works on the second click forward?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I made an onclick with js where it toggles the color of a textarea's text between red and green.(starts as red)
Any ideas why the onclick starts to work after the second click but not right away ?

```js
function todocheckdone(){
  var el = document.getElementById("task1");   
    
if (el.style.color === "red"){
    el.style.color = "green";
    }
  
  else{
    el.style.color = "red";
}}
```

```css
#todosnumbering{
   font-size: 18px;
    top: 18px;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
#task1{
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    color: red;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 358px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 16px;
    left: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
   
    }
#todocheck1{
    
    top: 20px;
    left: 406px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" id="todocheck1" onclick="todocheckdone()"
>✓</button>
<div id="todosnumbering">1.</div>
<textarea id="task1">THIS TEXT TOGGLES BETWEEN GREEN AND RED</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: element.style only retrieves inline style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the `.style.someProp` of an element will only give you style properties assigned *directly to the element*. Since the element doesn't have the `color` property directly assigned to it initially, accessing `.style.color` gives you the empty string the first time the function runs.

Instead of setting the style directly, I'd toggle a class:

```js
function todocheckdone() {
  var el = document.getElementById("task1");
  el.classList.toggle('green');
}
```

```css
#todosnumbering {
  font-size: 18px;
  top: 18px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

#task1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 358px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 16px;
  left: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
}

#task1.green {
  color: green;
}

#todocheck1 {
  top: 20px;
  left: 406px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="todocheck1" onclick="todocheckdone()">✓</button>
<div id="todosnumbering">1.</div>
<textarea id="task1">THIS TEXT TOGGLES BETWEEN GREEN AND RED</textarea>
```